# QGIS Browser for version 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-browser

I remember the browser version coming with the install package in QGIS 2.1.8 (or so??) but cannot find the install for version 3 QGIS anywhere!  Am I missing something?  Please let me know where I can download the browser application..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standalone QGIS Browser has been removed with QGIS 3. You can read it in the [changelog for QGIS 3.0](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/index.html#browser).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe vote for some kind of return of the qbrowser, see
- https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34267

One solution is to try to purge the gis-ppa and rollback to the 2.x release.  It's going to lose other benefits of the gis-ppa, but might recover the older qgis app (not highly recommended), i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo purge-ppa ppa:ubuntugis/ppa  # rolls back installed packages
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install qgis
qbrowser  # is back!
```